# Unable to compile llvm pass on Windows using Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clang, llvm

Im learning how to use the llvm toolchain on Windows.
I compiled and installed llvm using the following cmake command

```
cmake -S llvm -B build -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=lld -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\llvm" -Thost=x64
```

Running the `INSTALL` project in the solution created in the build folder installed llvm in `c:\llvm`.
To test my llvm installation i created a new Visual Studio project and placed a `Directory.build.props` file in the project root with the following contents:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LLVMInstallDir>C:\llvm</LLVMInstallDir>
    <LLVMToolsVersion>14.0.0</LLVMToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I set the project toolchain to `LLVM (clang-cl)` in project settings and successfully compiled a hello world program.
Now i wanna use llvm for it's intended use and play around with some passes. So i downloaded https://github.com/tsarpaul/llvm-string-obfuscator.
Running `cmake -Bbuild -DLLVM_DIR=C:\llvm\lib\cmake\llvm\` generated a Visual Studio solution in `.\build`.
So far so good i tought. This is similar to the steps required to compile llvm itself.
But running the `BUILD_ALL` project in the generated solution gave me 105 linker errors.
[image: Errors]

I have pasted the entire error output here: https://pastebin.com/TAizbAEi.
I have a feeling the required libraries in `C:\llvm\lib` are not visible to Visual Studio. But i have no idea how to proceed. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to use llvm with visual studio correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding to the cmake file:

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs core)
target_link_libraries(LLVMStringObfuscator ${llvm_libs})
```

Now the dll build.
I still have problems using `opt.exe`

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos> C:\llvm\bin\opt.exe -load-pass-plugin=.\11philip22\llvm-string-obfuscator\build\StringObfuscator\Release\LLVMStringObfuscator.dll -passes="string-obfuscator-pass"
C:\llvm\bin\opt.exe: .\11philip22\llvm-string-obfuscator\build\StringObfuscator\Release\LLVMStringObfuscator.dll:1:1: error: expected top-level entity
MZÉ           ╕       @                                   ║ ┤  ═!╕L═!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

But that's a new problem for another thread :)